# Symfony2 PUGXMultiUserBundle : registration doesn't work

Tags: symfony

I am trying to use PUGXMultiUserBundle in my application ; I followed the instructions in documentation, but when I go on the registration page, I got an error :

> Impossible to set the class discriminator, because the class "Myapp\UserBundle\Entity\SellerUser" is not present in the entities list

I think that everything is well configured, but I can't see where the bug is.

Comment: Could you show your configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my problem quickly ; in the documentation, it is written that you should put the configuration relative to the bundle into the bundle's config.yml (ie MyApp\MyBundle\Resources\config\config.yml)

I putted it into the app config.yml and it works ; don't know if it is a known issue, but for me it solved the problem

EDIT : just had to import my bundle's config.yml from the app config.yml to get it working, everything is fine and understood now

Comment: Can you copy/paste the lines that you moved, just to help me properly configure it? I'm trying to make it work with FOSUSERBundle but without success.

Comment: I've just lost 4 hours because I'm new to Symfony and the documentation has a typo in the https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md at the section: `Configure the FOSUserBundle (PUGXMultiUserBundle params)`: the `service:` line is idented by 2 spaces too much, which makes the yml file not valid. And I tried to indent it by adding 2 spaces... so all the options of `service:` section were ignored because the 2 spaces are **to be removed** not to add 2 spaces...

Answer (score 1):

@JérémyDutheil

That is not a solution to this problem. It is similar to put the PUGXMultiUserBundle configuration code in app/config.yml or in relative bundles config file and importing it to app/config.yml.

You forgot to configure PUGXMultiUserBundle in your config file. You have to define your user entities as given below:

```
pugx_multi_user:
  users:
    user_one:
        entity: 
          class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserOne

    user_two:
        entity: 
          class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserTwo
```

This is the appropriate solution for the problem you posted.

Comment: You are right having the config in app/config or imported from the bundle is the same thing. I don't know how @JérémyDutheil solved his issue. I must has been a typo or something. Thanks for the solution anyway